# Odd Color Shift after Merging Rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal-merge

I have a large number of raster orthophotos that I'm trying to merge into a single image using QGIS. The merge completes but the color is significantly off afterwards, as shown here:

[image: Color Shift after Merge]

This seems like it should be a very simple operation, so I must be missing some key piece of information.

I've placed two of the original orthophotos here in case someone wants to try this and help me figure it out:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnssxgmb2jfhrj3/Aerials.zip?dl=0

Comment: A few questions that might help you troubleshoot this: 1. Are the appropriate bands being merged (i.e. did red get merged with red, not with green)? 2. Have you checked the symbology of the merged layers to confirm that the layer that should be red is being drawn in red? 3. Do your original images each span the same range of values for a given layer?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to check your first or third question. The original orthos come from the same source and appear to have the same properties as shown in QGIS layer properties. There are three bands and the compression type is YCbCr JPEG.

Comment: After merging and then looking at the Symbology properties of the resulting layer, it appears that the Red, Green, and Blue bands all have various Min & Max values. If I set all the range for all three bands to 0-255, the image looks as it should. So I suppose the question is, how do I get this to be the default behavior as opposed to having to fix each merged image after it's created?

Comment: Default raster rendering settings are in the settings menu > options > rendering.